# Strange translation of jOOQ query for array contains function

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

I have the following type in my PostgreSQL database :

```
myoptions text[]
```

I use a jOOQ converter so that I have a Set as corresponding type in my record :

```
Set<String> myoptions
```

In my query I have the following Condition :

```
c.MYOPTIONS.contains(Sets.newHashSet("option1"))
```

which is translated in SQL like this :

```
cast("c"."myoptions" as varchar) like ('%' || '[option1]' || '%') escape '!'
```

Is it the normal behavior ?

I would like to have something like :

```
c.myoptions @> ARRAY['option1']
```

or

```
'option1' = ANY(c.myoptions)
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jOOQ currently (as of version 3.8) does not recognise your custom data type as still being an array data type in PostgreSQL, which is why the `Field.contains()` default behaviour kicks in - i.e. the one that treats all values as strings.

I've created [feature request #5602](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5602) for this. As a workaround, you might need to roll your own using [plain SQL](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/):

```
public static <T, C extends Collection<T>> Condition contains(
    Field<? extends C> left, 
    C right
) {
    return DSL.condition("{0} @> {1}::text[]", left, DSL.val(right, left.getDataType()));
}
```

... which you can then use as such:

```
contains(c.MYOPTIONS, Sets.newHashSet("option1"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you please tell me how to use your static function ?

Comment: Thanks but the 2 types doesn't seem to be compatible,  I have the following error now : Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'org.jooq.TableField<CopyRecord,java.util.Set<java.lang.String>>', required: 'org.jooq.Field<? extends C>'

Comment: @Manu: I'm sorry, my answer was quite wrong... Please check out the update. The first argument is still a column reference, whereas the second argument should be that `Set<String>` that you originally used, not an array.

Comment: Thank you very much again. Now I have a problem of type cast : PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: text[] @> character varying[]  --- Because it generates the following SQL : ("c"."myoptions" @> ?::varchar[])

Comment: Any idea to make a generic cast ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Manu: Sorry, I'm currently on the road. Will get back to this soon.

Comment: @Manu: I'm sorry, I cannot think of anything other than explicitly casting the value back to `::text[]` right now. There's probably a deeper problem with the fact that jOOQ treats all strings as `varchar` in PostgreSQL, rather than as `text`, but I'm not sure if that is still a reasonable thing to discuss in the context of this question.

Comment: Ok ! thank you for your help and of course thanks a lot for jOOQ !

Answer (score 2):

Please try following solution. Worked in my case.

```
select.where(ARRAY_FIELD.contains(DSL.cast(DSL.array(VALUE), ARRAY_FIELD.getDataType())));
```

Comment: This solved the following error for me: `Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.`